# Is $T':L^2(\Omega) \to L^2(\Omega)$ continuous?

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity

Here, $k$ is a fixed number. Let $$T(x) = \begin{cases}
-k &x \in (-\infty, -k]\\
x &x \in (-k, k)\\
k &x \in [k, \infty)
\end{cases}.$$
So $$T'(x) = \begin{cases}
0 &x \in (-\infty, -k)\\
1 &x \in (-k, k)\\
0 &x \in (k, \infty)
\end{cases}.$$
Let $\Omega$ be a bounded domain.

**Problem 1**

Suppose $f_n \to f$ in $L^2(\Omega)$. Does it follow that $T'(f_n) \to T'(f)$ in $L^2(\Omega)$ as $n \to \infty$?

---

**Problem 2**

Suppose $f_n \to f$ in $H^1(\Omega)$. Does it follow that $T(f_n) \to T(f)$ in $H^1(\Omega)$ as $n \to \infty$?

I can show continuity in $L^2$ using the DCT. For the $H^1$ seminorm, not sure how to find a dominant function on $|T'(f_n)\nabla f_n| \leq |\nabla f_n|$ independent of $n$. And as pointed out in the comment, $T'$ is not defined at $\pm k$.

---

Comment: Is it really trivial? We have $T_k'(f_n) = \chi_{\{f_n(x) \in (-k, k)\}}$. The original question I think I can solve if I know this. Maybe I will edit the original one in.

Comment: So, you are not actually letting $k\to \infty$ (I misread). Then the first part is hopeless: $f$ could be on one side of cutoff, and $f_n$ could converge to it from the other side. Counterexample is given by  constant functions. BTW you did not even define $T_k'(k)$, without which you don't have a definition of $T_k'\circ f$.

Comment: Now $k$ tends to $0$? And $n$ to infinity, simultaneously?  OK, I'll take a break from this question for a week or so, while you figure out what you want to ask.

Comment: Sorry! $n \to \infty$.$k$ is fixed. Better if i just removed subscript $k$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For problem 1, you have an issue that by your current definition, $T'(f)$ is undefined if $f$ takes on the value $\pm k$ (on a set of positive measure).  Indeed, if $f$ is the constant function $k$, then $T(f)$ is undefined everywhere.

You could try to fix this by setting $T'(k) = 0$ or $T'(k) = 1$ or something, but it won't get you continuity.  Indeed, it is not hard to prove that:

> If $g : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and $f \mapsto g \circ f$ is continuous on $L^2(\Omega)$, then $g$ is continuous.

(Hint: You only have to think about $f$ ranging over the constant functions.)

Comment: Which illustrates the classical $X/Y$ problem. Problem 1 is dead on arrival (as you pointed out) but the OP actually wanted 2, which is a standard fact about truncation in first-order Sobolev spaces.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem 1**: as already noted, this is not true. See Nate Eldredge's answer and also [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/822814/convergence-of-chi-x-mid-u-nx-in-i-to-chi-x-mid-ux-in-i/822881?noredirect=1#comment1701628_822881).

**Problem 2**: this is true. The truncation function can be written as a sum of $\max$ and $\min$, which have nice properties (applying these functions to a differentiable function preserves differentiability, they are sequentially continuous etc). See Lemma 2.89 on page 35 in [this book](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=b_l0KTevQ0wC&pg=PA34&dq=piecewise+C%5E1+lipschitz+function+chain+rule&hl=en&sa=X&ei=sMCSU4ORPIPX7Abn9YC4Bg&ved=0CFcQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=piecewise%20C%5E1%20lipschitz%20function%20chain%20rule&f=false) for a proof for a generalised truncation function.