# Convergence of $\chi_{\{x \mid u_n(x) \in I\}} \to \chi_{\{x \mid u(x) \in I\}}$ for $u_n \to u$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, characteristic-functions

Let $u_n \to u$ in $L^2(\Omega)$ and let $I$ be an bounded interval.

Does it follow that $$\chi_{\{x \mid u_n(x) \in I\}} \to \chi_{\{x \mid u(x) \in I\}}$$
at least for a subsequence of $u_{n_j}$ (because we will have pointwise convergence for $u_{n_j} \to u$ a.e.)

It appears true but no idea how to prove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following counter example: $f_n \equiv 1 - 1/n$ on $\Omega = (0, 3)$ (you could also take any finite measure space), $I = [1, 4)$ and $f\equiv 1$. You can also take $I = (0,1)$ or $ I = [1,4]$, showing that this fails for all types of intervals.

Comment: Thanks, but $f_n$ never takes values in $I$, right? Does the same conclusion hold (if only for a subsequence) if $f_n$ does take values in $I$?

Comment: You can use $\Omega = (0,3)\cup (5,6)$ and set $f_n = y_0 = f$ on $(5,6)$ (and the old construction on the rest), with $y_0 \in I$.